# Struggling with passing data from Array to another Array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

So I got a problem with Arrays in a C code. I think the problem is nothing serious, but after working over 48 hours on my code I just can't really see through.
So here's my problem: I got a function called path, which finds the shortest path between two given point in a maze. The function returns an int variable, I named stepcount. Here I store the number of steps needed from one Point to the other. This information is stored in an array called "comb". This array is two dimensional.

```
agents = atoi( argv[4] );
int k=0;
unsigned int num = agents*agents;
unsigned int comb[num][3];//Represents steps form one agent to the target ->
//[][1] = Startpoint; [][2] = Endpoint; [][3] = number of steps;
unsigned int distance[agents][3];

for(int i=0; i<agents; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<agents; j++)
    {
        stepcount=path(nodeAgents[i], nodeTargets[j]);
        comb[k][0]=i;
        comb[k][1]=j;
        comb[k][2]=stepcount;
        k++;
    }
}

for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
{
    printf("%d. Steps from Agent %d to Target needed %d: %d\n",i, comb[i][0],comb[i][1],comb[i][2]);
}
```

So I get the number of steps needed from the position of an agent to all targets in the maze. Now I want to find the nearest target to the agent. Therefore I programmed this code:

```
for(int i=0; i<num; i+agents)
{
    for(int j=k; j<agents; j++)
    {
        if(comb[j+i][2]<comb[j+i+1][2])
        {
            distance[j][0] = i;
            distance[j][1] = j;
            distance[j][2] = comb[j+i][2];
        }
    }
}

for(int i=0; i<agents; i++)
{
    int j = distance[i][0];
    int x = distance[i][1];
    int y = distance[i][2];
    printf("%d. Nearest Target to Agent %d is Target %d. The number of steps needed is %d\n", i, j, x, y);
}
```

But something must be wrong in this segment of my code, because the program stops there. So currently I just can't figure out what I forgot, or did wrong. So I hope maybe someone, can give me a hint, before I go nuts.

Comment: Also, shouldn't `comb[k][0]=i` (and others) be `comb[>>>j<<<][0]=i`.  (It is difficult to see the entire context of `k`, Since the entire functions are not shown)

Comment: @Ryyker: I know my code isn't the prettiest, but I know that this code is working. I already use this kind of code before. So I think the problem have to be in the second code segment.

Comment: @iharob: What do you mean by buffer overflows?

Comment: is this `i+agents` mean to be `i += agents`? and this does look like will overflow the array `if(comb[j+i][2]<comb[j+i+1][2])`...

Comment: Do you mean in for(int i=0; i<num; i+agents). No, my idea here was that I got for example 5 agent, which means I also got 5 targets. So I calculate the distance from agent one to all 5 targets, and so on. So in the array comb the first 5 rows are for agent one, the next 5 for agent to and so on. So I thought I increase everytime by the number of agents.

Comment: Ok, but the `i+agents` does not do that, it should be `i+=agents`

Comment: Also in a for loop. I thought if I want to increase the variable i everytime the loop runs through by two, I write for(i=0; i<...; i+2)

Comment: Following @iharob, the statement `i+2` has no more consequence than the statement `i`. You need `i+=2`